# Facebook Android SDK: how to get Open Graph Object from URL?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-opengraph, facebook-android-sdk, facebook-sharer

On the Facebook documentation I have only found the way to build a `ShareOpenGraphObject` by manually specifying the fields:

```
    ShareOpenGraphObject object = new ShareOpenGraphObject.Builder()
            .putString("og:type", "books.book")
            .putString("og:title", "A Game of Thrones")
            .putString("og:description", "In the frozen wastes to the north of Winterfell, sinister and supernatural forces are mustering.")
            .putString("books:isbn", "0-553-57340-3")
            .build();
    ShareOpenGraphAction action = new ShareOpenGraphAction.Builder()
            .setActionType("books.reads")
            .putObject("book", object)
            .build();
    ShareOpenGraphContent content = new ShareOpenGraphContent.Builder()
            .setPreviewPropertyName("book")
            .setAction(action)
            .build();
    ShareDialog.show(this, content);
```

How can I build a `ShareOpenGraphObject` just by specifying a URL (which contains the FB Open Graph tags defining the object) ?

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution!

On the `ShareOpenGraphAction.Builder()`, instead of specifying the `ShareOpenGraphObject` with `putObject()`, you specify the Open Graph Object URL with `putString()`

```
    ShareOpenGraphAction action = new ShareOpenGraphAction.Builder()
            .setActionType("books.reads")
            .putString("book", "http://www.myserver.com/my_object_page")
            .build();
    ShareOpenGraphContent content = new ShareOpenGraphContent.Builder()
            .setPreviewPropertyName("book")
            .setAction(action)
            .build();
    ShareDialog.show(this, content);
```